# How to view file changes before pulling through GitHub on RStudio?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, svn, rstudio

I'm transitioning from using Subversion in Eclipse for code management to  GitHub in RStudio.  It's starting to make sense, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull effectively.

Specifically, if I use the Pull arrow in RStudio, every file change in the repository automatically updates my local files without warning.  I can see how many files were updated, but not what changed!

*Here are the questions I'm hoping to get help with:*

**1)**  Can I preview the repository file changes in RStudio before I pull them locally?  With SVN in Eclipse, there was an indicator showing files with a difference, and the option to view side by side.

**2)**  If multiple files have been changed on the repository, is it possible to pull just 1 locally?

**3)**  How can I revert a local file to a previous version?

Right now I've been trying to do this all within RStudio for simplicity.  I haven't used things like the GitHub desktop client.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you better get used to the git's own tools to stay informed about your repository.

For example you could do following.

Before you pull, check your current commit logs

> git log

This should show you how your current commits stack up. Note the latest commit id (first 4-5 letters would usually do)
Now after pulling you can see the difference using following command

> git diff --color your_previous_commit_id..HEAD

If you don't like the changes and want to go back,
you can just reset to your favorite commit with following command. BTW run "git stash save" to keep a copy of your uncommitted changes.

> git reset --hard you_favorite_commit_id

Note: that this will delete all your uncommitted changes unless you stashed them and put your local branch behind the remote repo branch you are tracking again.

Wondering where to put these commands? Check https://git-scm.com/downloads.
What's good about using these git tools is that if you switch between IDEs you don't need to search for same functionalities you had in your earlier IDEs.